QGIS: Edit lines so that they all start from the same side
I have a project where its important to say which side of the street cars are parked. I am having difficult with the data because left or right depends on where the first point of the line was made. This is irregular which means I have to manually edit each line to so that my labeling is on the correct side of the road.
This image is to help illustrate the problem. I am looking for a way to edit the lines so that the first points all start from one side. This would help speed up my workflow.


How do you define the "right" end of the line to start?

Approximate algorithm:

Difine line direction (angle/azimuth) with Extract vertices tool.

Select lines with specific direction (angle/azimuth).

Reverse selected lines with Reverse line direction



Thanks to Comrade Che!
I find the angle with :
round(degrees(bearing(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry),
'EPSG:3857',
'EPSG:7030')),0)
and then select all lines with an angle more than 180° to be reversed.
Now all lines are facing the same way i can create a symbol styling more efficiently.

